# Problem with wheezy theme

Tags: gnome, software-installation, debian, theme

I am a totally newcomer to Debian wheezy, and I can't install the Asian_Catharsis.tar.lzma theme from gnome-look.org; I've also copied it to ~/.themes yet no effects I earn.

Also, I've changed my theme to "Gnome Classic" and every time I try to use 'Gdebi' to install 'gnome-art_0.2-12_all.deb' It returns the error : 'Error: Dependency is not Satisfiable: libgnome2-ruby'.

Can you help me fix the issues or introduce me an alternative way to easily download and install themes?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way (and maybe a help): install the gnome extension "User themes" to allow local user themes.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/

You can switch it on/off and change settings with `gnome-tweak-tool` (you might need to install it first)

There are also some theme packages in the repository:

`aptitude install gnome-theme-gilouche gnome-themes gnome-themes-extras gnome-themes-standard gnome-themes-standard-data`

or

`apt-get install gnome-theme-gilouche gnome-themes gnome-themes-extras gnome-themes-standard gnome-themes-standard-data`

(always use the same installation tool for database/dependency stability!)